# Converting a RealmCollectionChange to an IndexPath in RealmSwift

Tags: swift, realm, realm-list

I have a UITableView that updates when there is a RealmCollectionChange. I want to know how to convert a modified object's child to an IndexPath so that I can reload the relevant row in that TableView section.

Each table section header in my TableView is represented by a Mum in the Granny.secondGeneration List. Each TableViewCell in that section is represented by each Kid object in the Mum.thirdGeneration List.

[image]

When a Kid object is modified, I want to access that tableRow Index to reload it. But the modifications array only returns the section/section index, I'm not sure how to get the rowIndex from that to reload just the Kid TableViewCell.

```
    class Granny:Object {
        
        @Persisted var name:String = ""
        @Persisted var secondGeneration = RealmSwift.List<Mum>()
    }
    
    class Mum:Object {
        
        @Persisted var name:String = ""
        @Persisted var thirdGeneration = RealmSwift.List<Kid>()
    }
    
    class Kid:Object {
        @Persisted var name:String = ""
    }

    ...
  
    let granny = Granny(name: "Sheila")
    let mum = Mum(name: "Mary")
    granny.secondGeneration.append(mum)
    let kid1 = Kid(name: "Lola")
    let kid2 = Kid(name: "Greg")
    mum.thirdGeneration.append(kid1)
    mum.thirdGeneration.append(kid2)
    
    RealmManager.add(object: granny)
    ...
    notificationToken = granny.secondGeneration.observe { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        guard let tableView = self?.tableView else { return }
        switch changes {
        case .initial:
            // Results are now populated and can be accessed without blocking the UI
            tableView.reloadData()
        case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            
            print("Insertions: \(insertions.count) Deletions:\(deletions.count) Modifications: \(modifications)")

tableView.beginUpdates()
                    
                    
                    if !modifications.isEmpty {
                        let modificationsSectionIndex = modifications.map({ IndexSet(integer: $0) })[0]
                        // This reloads the 'Mum' section header, but I want to find out the row index of the modified child 
                        tableView.reloadSections(modificationsSectionIndex, with: .automatic)
                    }

                    tableView.endUpdates()
            
        case .error(let error):
            // An error occurred while opening the Realm file on the background worker thread
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I kinda understand the question but your code won't work as is and needs to be corrected so it's clear. First, `Granny` has a child property `secondGeneration` which is a `List` of type `Mum`. However, the code defines a `Kid` with `let mum = Kid(name: "Mary")` and then attempts to append it to the `secondGeneration` property of type `Mum` here `granny.secondGeneration.append(mum)`. That won't work. There are other issues (you've got two `kid1` defined). Then the observer is only on `granny.secondGeneration` which does not contain what's shown in the screenshot. Also why this `[0]` in the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to approach this at a high level with simplified code - I think that will make the solution more clear.

Answer: Change your logic. Instead of observing the `Parent` class looking for changes in `Children`, observe the `Children` class who know who their `Parent` is.

Here's the setup using Persons and Dogs, which is analogous to a parent->child relationship

```
class PersonClass: Object {
    @Persisted var name = ""
    @Persisted var dogList = RealmSwift.List<DogClass>()
}

class DogClass: Object {
    @Persisted var name = ""
    @Persisted(originProperty: "dogList") var linkedPersons: LinkingObjects<PersonClass>
}
```

There are persons who have dogs (similar to your setup) so Realm will look like this

```
person0
  dog0
  dog1
person2
  dog3
  dog4
```

Then, populate dogResults and attach an observer

```
self.dogResults = realm.objects(DogClass.self)
self.dogsToken = self.dogResults!.observe { changes in
```

And then here's what happens in the update (note addition for first parameter 'changedItems'

```
case .update(let changedItems, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications ):
```

section: modified

```
let paths = modifications.map { (index) -> IndexPath in
    //the dog that was modified in the dogs results
    let modifiedDog = changedItems[index]

    //the owner of this dog e.g. the section header
    let owner = modifiedDog.linkingPerson.first! 

    //the index of the person section
    let sectionIndex = self.peopleResults?.index(of: owner)

    //the row within the section of this modified dog
    let rowIndex = owner.dogList.index(of: modifiedDog) 

    //the IndexPath to the dog row within the section
    let path = IndexPath(item: rowIndex!, section: sectionIndex!) 

    print(path) //print each path

    return path
}
```

We now have and array of index paths for the sections/rows that need to be updated. If it's never going to be multiple row updates at the same time, the map can be removed to just address one row at a time